# Failed to enable connection: out of resource error PiCamera

Tags: python, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3

I am creating my thesis device which uses a PiCam. My problem is that every time I use my camera after it captures an image, it can't be used again and display an error when I click the button on my GUI to start the camera again:

picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources

How can I stop the camera in a way after it captures an image it also stops the using of the resource for the picamera?

This is my code for my camera:

```
def startcam():
        camera = PiCamera()
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.jpg")
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.start_preview()
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(16, False)
        GPIO.output(13, True)
        camera.capture(filename)
        GPIO.output(13, False)
        sleep(1)
        camera.stop_preview()
        webbrowser.open(filename)
```

The GPIO codes are for my LED flash and IR led cuz I am using a NOIR camera.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture many images, you should declare the camera globally outside the function:

```
camera=Picamera()
def startcam():
   GPIO.output(16, True)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small program that takes a sequence of pics. It worked fine in IDLE, but from command line came up with exact same error being out of resources. The problem was fixed by adding `camera.close()` after except KeyboardInterrupt: in the program, i.e. `Ctrl+C` (in the Python shell). usually used when you need to break out of a loop.